# Helm default value throws error converting YAML to JSON

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a basic kubernetes helm template like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
data:
  config.tpl: |
{{- default ((tpl .Values.configTpl .) | indent 4)  (tpl (.Files.Get "files/config.tpl") . | indent 4) -}}
```

and the values.yml file

```
configTpl: |
   {{ x=8gwifi.org }}
```

When i apply the helm chart it throw me an error

```
❯ helm upgrade  mychart . --namespace=test --create-namespace --debug
upgrade.go:142: [debug] preparing upgrade for mychart
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on 8gwifi.org-test/templates/configmap-logfilegen.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 11: did not find expected comment or line break
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 11: did not find expected comment or line break
```

I tried different configuration

```
config.tpl: |
    {{- default (tpl .Values.configTpl . | indent 4) (tpl (.Files.Get "files/config.tpl") . | indent 4) -}}
```

still resulting in same error, Is there a way to specify a config value if none is passed then used the hardcoded one

I'm sure it's an YAML syntx issue couldn't figure it out checked all cases

**Based on David suggestion**

Template debug is showing this

```
data:
  config.tpl: |-
       x := 8gwifi.org
   y := "functions"
```

**I can cleary see y is not indent and throwing YAML syntax error, not sure how to fix this**

This is the updated definition

```
data:
  config.tpl: |-
    {{ (tpl .Values.configTpl . | indent 4)  | default (tpl (.Files.Get "files/config.tpl") . | indent 4) -}}
```

values.yml

```
configTpl: |
   x := "8gwifi.org"
   y := "function"
```

Comment: config.tpl: |-
{{- default ((tpl .Values.configTpl .) | indent 4)  (tpl (.Files.Get "files/config.tpl") . | indent 4) -}}
added a extra hyphen for multiple line support, try this?

Comment: Hi Bijendra this throw me same error ?

Comment: If you run `helm template --debug` over the chart, is it obvious how the generated YAML is wrong?  (I suspect the `-` before `default`, and you'd see the content on the same line `config.tpl: |{{ ... }}` in that case.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I have updated the response I can see Y is not getting indent well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting problems with whitespace in the first line of the block scalar.  You should check two things:

1. The template block containing `indent` must not itself be indented, it must start at the first column of its line; and
2. The template block containing `indent` must not have a `-` inside the opening curly braces.

```yaml
{{- $configTpl := .Values.configTpl | default (.Files.Get "tiles/config.tpl") }}
  config.tpl: |
{{ tpl $configTpl . | indent 4 }}
```

The templating language isn't really aware of YAML syntax as it runs.  If you have spaces in front of the `indent` line, they will get emitted, and then `indent` adds its own leading space, resulting in the last output you get where the first line is indented extra.  The `-` whitespace control marker will also consume the preceding newline, resulting in the first line of the output being on the same line as the YAML block scalar marker.